# import cvs with binary columns from CSV to DB

Tags: sql-server, csv, ssis

I want to achieve the following simple ETL:
input: file.csv which has three columns one of which is binary and presented in hexadecimal format (like 0xFF7A726). I need to import the data and then convert binary value back to integer. What have i tried (this is inside data flow task having two sources):

- using derived columns and specifying casting like this: (DT_UI8)(DT_BYTES,50)BinaryColumn
- trying to leave column as string and expect that implicit cast will occur
- trying to create one more varbinary column and try to convert dt_string to dt_bytes and then map to varbinary column

Does anyone had experience in importing data from cvs which has binary data? Can someone share some ideas in which direction i need to dig through?

Comment: From my experience, using excel to make all the fields as text. And using sql server import data function, then you can get the data in correct. After that, using cast function to make the data as you want.( You can create another table or just use it.)

Answer (score 0):

I've done it the opposite way around - converting from varbinary in the database to base64 values for a csv, if this is what you mean?
Similar to what Loser suggests, importing all to varchar columns on a staging table then doing a convert afterwards might work.
This CLR function method may work too :-
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqltips/archive/2008/06/30/converting-from-base64-to-varbinary-and-vice-versa.aspx